# lambda function on list in dataframe column error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

I have a list of numbers inside of a pandas dataframe and i am trying to use a lambda function + list comprehension to remove values from these lists.

col 1    col2

a        [-1, 2, 10, 600, -10]

b        [-0, -5, -6, -200, -30]

c        .....

etc.

```
df.col2.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i>= 0]) #just trying to remove negative values
```

numbers are always ascending and can be all negative, all positive or a mix. lists are about 200 items long all integers.

I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Edit: when i do it this way it works
`[i for i in df[col2][#] if i >= 0]` i guess i could run this through a for loop.. seems slow though

Edit2: looking at it with fresh eyes. turns out that the column isn't entirely made up of lists there are a few float values spread throughout (duh). Something weird was going on with the merge, once i corrected that the code above worked as expected. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The error says what your problem is. Try making the `lambda` a variable, convert your column into a list, then pass it through.

Comment: the error makes no sense to me. lambda x is a list why would there be a type error? if i do:
```
[i for i in df[col2][#] if i >= 0] 
```
this works

Comment: Is every item in column 2 a list of numbers or is there any instance in which its a single float instead of a list?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of how apply works

Comment: Look into masks and conditions

Answer (score 1):

Because `x` in your lambda is a float number, and you cant loop over float :p.
if you need to do so. you can

```python
In [2]: np.random.seed(4)
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-5,5, 7)).rename(columns={0:"col2"})
   ...: df.col2 = df.col2.astype(float)
   ...: df
Out[2]: 
   col2
0   2.0
1   0.0
2  -4.0
3   3.0
4   2.0
5   3.0
6  -3.0

In [3]: df.col2.apply(lambda x: x if x > 0 else None).dropna()
Out[3]: 
0    2.0
3    3.0
4    2.0
5    3.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why not just `df.col2[df.col2 >= 0]`?

Comment: Because `df.col2[df.col2 >= 0]` return only >= 0 values so you can't append resulting column to existing df, , on the other hand `df.col2.apply(lambda x: x if x > 0 else None)` return the same length so you can append it to existing df.